# Are Some Bible Scripture verses merely monotonously descriptive/instructive Or do they have more meaningful undertones?(layers of meaning)

Tags: layers-of-meaning, literary-structure, literary-genre, literary-device

Some bible passages may seem to just have monotonously descriptive/instructive tones (especially the bible books of Chronicles, Leviticus, Kings, etc. ), but the bible reader is usually left wondering if there is more meaning to said passages or some undertones to said passages.

For example, in 2 Samuel 3:12-16 bible passage,

would it be correct to say said passage is merely monotonously reporting/describing that Michal was returned to her 1st husband, David, and that her 2nd husband, Paltiel the son of Laish, was weeping and crying because Michal had to return to her 1st husband?

**Or**

Would the bible reader be able to infer/deduce that Michal was a cold ice queen/uncaring/arrogant woman who did Not care about  Paltiel the son of Laish's weeping because she was returning to her 1st husband, David, who ascended to be King of Israel and Judah? ( I say arrogant woman because it is evidenced in (2 Samuel 6:16-23) where Michal's despises King David due to what she sees as his unsophisticated/inelegant behaviour of dancing during worship )

> (2 Samuel 3:12-16)
>
> 12 Then Abner sent messengers to David in his
> place, saying, “Whose is the land? Make your covenant with me, and
> behold, my hand shall be with you to bring all Israel over to you.”
> 13 He said, “Good! I will make a covenant with you, but I demand one
> thing of you, [c]namely, you shall not see my face unless you first
> bring Michal, Saul’s daughter, when you come to see [d]me.” 14 So
> David sent messengers to Ish-bosheth, Saul’s son, saying, “Give me my
> wife Michal, to whom I was betrothed for a hundred foreskins of the
> Philistines.” 15 Ish-bosheth sent and took her from her husband, from
> [e]Paltiel the son of Laish. 16 But her husband went with her, weeping
> as he went, and followed her as far as Bahurim. Then Abner said to
> him, “Go, return.” So he returned.

> (2 Samuel 6:16-23)
>
> 16 Then it happened as the ark of the Lord came
> into the city of David that Michal the daughter of Saul looked out of
> the window and saw King David leaping and dancing before the Lord; and
> she despised him in her
> heart...........................................blah.....blah.......................................20 But
> when David returned to bless his household, Michal the daughter of
> Saul came out to meet David and said, “How the king of Israel
> distinguished himself today! He uncovered himself today in the eyes of
> his servants’ maids as one of the foolish ones shamelessly uncovers
> himself!” 21 So David said to Michal, “It was before the Lord, who
> chose me above your father and above all his house, to appoint me
> ruler over the people of the Lord, over Israel; therefore I will
> celebrate before the Lord. 22 I will be more lightly esteemed than
> this and will be humble in my own eyes, but with the maids of whom you
> have spoken, with them I will be distinguished.” 23 Michal the
> daughter of Saul had no child to the day of her death.

Answer (score 2):

Are Some Bible Scripture verses merely monotonously descriptive/instructive Or do they have more meaningful undertones?(layers of meaning)

Yes, they do have more meaningful undertones. A good example is the curtains in Exodus 26:

> 1“Make the tabernacle with ten curtains of finely twisted linen and blue, purple and scarlet yarn, with cherubim woven into them by a skilled worker. 2All the curtains are to be the same size—twenty-eight cubits long and four cubits wide. a 3Join five of the curtains together, and do the same with the other five. 4Make loops of blue material along the edge of the end curtain in one set, and do the same with the end curtain in the other set. 5Make fifty loops on one curtain and fifty loops on the end curtain of the other set, with the loops opposite each other. 6Then make fifty gold clasps and use them to fasten the curtains together so that the tabernacle is a unit.
>
> 7“Make curtains of goat hair for the tent over the tabernacle—eleven altogether. 8All eleven curtains are to be the same size—thirty cubits long and four cubits wide. b 9Join five of the curtains together into one set and the other six into another set. Fold the sixth curtain double at the front of the tent. 10Make fifty loops along the edge of the end curtain in one set and also along the edge of the end curtain in the other set. 11Then make fifty bronze clasps and put them in the loops to fasten the tent together as a unit. 12As for the additional length of the tent curtains, the half curtain that is left over is to hang down at the rear of the tabernacle. 13The tent curtains will be a cubit c longer on both sides; what is left will hang over the sides of the tabernacle so as to cover it. 14Make for the tent a covering of ram skins dyed red, and over that a covering of the other durable leather.

This seems to be monotonous and mechanical instructions to make curtains: colors, materials, decorations, loops, folds, edges, etc. I'm sure they carry spiritual significances. The greatest of these significances is shown in the NT Matthew 27:

> 50 And when Jesus had cried out again in a loud voice, he gave up his spirit.
>
> 51At that moment the **curtain** of the temple was torn in two from top to bottom. The earth shook, the rocks split 52and the tombs broke open. The bodies of many holy people who had died were raised to life. 53They came out of the tombs after Jesus’ resurrection and e went into the holy city and appeared to many people.
>
> 54When the centurion and those with him who were guarding Jesus saw the earthquake and all that had happened, they were terrified, and exclaimed, “Surely he was the Son of God!”

2 Timothy 3:16

> **All** Scripture is God-breathed and is useful for teaching, rebuking, correcting and training in righteousness,

Paul was not kidding or exergerating when he said "All Scripture is God-breathed."

Jesus wasn't either:

Matthew 5:18

> For truly I tell you, until heaven and earth disappear, not the smallest letter, not the least stroke of a pen, will by any means disappear from the Law until everything is accomplished.

Comment: @tony-chan Thanks for referring to Exodus 26. Just FYI, the bible project video very briefly explains that the tabernacle's structure description has a lot of symbolism that relate to 
garden of eden https://youtu.be/oNpTha80yyE?t=182

Comment: @crazyTech BibleProject vids are AWESOME! I hear what you’re saying in your question though: can we infer a richer human interaction than the texts often imply. For that answer (over and above Tony’s meaningful cross references above), one would need an expert in ancient Hebrew language and culture to give insights into the double/multiple meanings of words- and even letters - in a particular passage or phrase. There might be cultural clues/cues also, hidden from our view due to our lack of understanding of Hebrew language and custom.

Answer (score 0):

> (2 Samuel 3:12-16)
>
> 12 Then Abner sent messengers to David in his place, saying, “Whose is the land? Make your covenant with me, and behold, my hand
> shall be with you to bring all Israel over to you.” 13 He said, “Good!
> I will make a covenant with you, but I demand one thing of you,
> [c]namely, you shall not see my face unless you first bring Michal,
> Saul’s daughter, when you come to see [d]me.” 14 So David sent
> messengers to Ish-bosheth, Saul’s son, saying, “Give me my wife
> Michal, to whom I was betrothed for a hundred foreskins of the
> Philistines.” 15 Ish-bosheth sent and took her from her husband, from
> [e]Paltiel the son of Laish. **16 But her husband went with her, weeping
> as he went, and followed her as far as Bahurim.** Then Abner said to
> him, “Go, return.” So he returned.

- I believe Michal was behaving like a cold ice queen/uncaring/arrogant
  woman.  The reason being is that if it were just merely monotonously
  reporting/describing in nature and/or had an instructive tone then it
  would Not mention/Not report that fact that Paltiel the son of Laish,
  Michal's 2nd husband, would weep and follow her.  The weeping &
  following seems to be too much detail which means that (2 Samuel
  3:12-16) leans towards being more like a story/novel as opposed to
  just some monotonous report.
- Furthermore, broadly speaking, most of the other
  narratives/sub-narratives in the Books of 1 Samuel & 2 Samuel lean
  towards being more like a story/novel.
  On the other hand, Books of
  Chronicles, Leviticus, Kings might lean more towards being more like
  a monotonous report.  Also, the books of Chronicles' name itself is
  an  autological word (also called homological word or autonym)
  because it means historical account.  Therefore, it makes sense that
  Chronicles leans towards like a monotonous report.